# Не работает phpmyadmin

Tags: ubuntu, phpmyadmin, lamp

в общем, у меня не работает phpmyadmin на Ubuntu 16.04, вместо страницы с формой входа отображается php код: `<?php
/* vim: set expandtab sw=4 ts=4 sts=4: */
/**
 * Main loader script
 *
 * @package PhpMyAdmin
 */`
И еще много-много подобных строк, как решить проблему? Раньше устанавливал все без проблем, а сейчас как-то так(

Comment: Apache/Nginx настроен неправильно

Comment: При установке я выбрал пункт "Автоматическая настройка через dbconfig-что-то там", или как-то так

Comment: Нужно прописать в конфиге обработку файлов с расширениями .php - http://php.net/manual/ru/install.unix.apache2.php

Comment: http-сервер не настроен на вызов интерпретатора *php*. как минимум для *url-ов*, относящимся к *phpmyadmin*